# django menu - language chooser - show only existing languages

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am not sure if someone had this issue before:

I have these pages in django cms's admin.

[image]

these are the pages I created using django cms and languages come from `LANGUAGES` from settings.py

and I used `{% language_chooser %}`, it dislays all languages which are defined in `LANGUAGES`.

What I want is: if I am in `home`, in language_chooser only those languages should show up for which there is a page created. in this case, only `english`, `german`, and `espaniol`

how can I achieve this? any guidance is appreciated

**SOLVED, BUT..**

I ended up using this inside language_chooser.html

```
{% load i18n menu_tags %}

{% get_available_languages as languages %}

{% if languages|length > 1 %}
 {% for language in languages %}
     {% if language.1 in current_page.get_languages %}
     <li class="lang{% ifequal current_language language.0 %} active{% endifequal %}">
        <a href="{% page_language_url language.0 %}"
           title="{% trans "Change to language:" %} {{ language.1 }}">{{ language.0 }}</a>
     </li>
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But this is showing up only in `home` page, not in other pages, any ideas? BTW, Other pages are AppHooks

Comment: somehow, ``current_page`` context variable isnot available in other pages. btw, other pages are apphooks

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up doing this:

```
{% if languages|length > 1 %}
 {% for language in languages %}
   <li class="lang{% ifequal current_language language.0 %} active{% endifequal %}">
    <a href="/./{{ language.0 }}/"
       title="{% trans "Change to language:" %} {{ language.1 }}">{{ language.0 }}</a>
   </li>
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

meaning.. just redirect the user to main page if they change the language.

`<a href="/./{{ language.0 }}/"` ..

and make sure to define in settings.py only those languages that your site has translations for..